# Spark Reading and Writing to same S3 Path Giving Unable to infer Schema Error

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to perform update insert (Upsert) on old data with new data.

Pseudo Code:

```
old_data = spark.read.parquet('s3://bucket/old_data/')
new_data= spark.read.parquet('s3://bucket/new_data/')

common_records = old_data.join(new_data,on=opk,how="inner")
non_match_records = old_data.join(new_data,on=opk,how="left_anti")
new_records = new_data.join(old_data,on=opk,how="left_anti")
dfs = [common_records , non_match_records , new_records ]
final_data = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, dfs)

final_data .cache()
final_data.write.parquet('s3://bucket/old_data/')
```

Error :

[image]

Even I cached data, Still It's Looking for old_data path, Is there anyway to directly write to old data s3 path.

I have tried it to write to some temp path and read from it and write to main path Like below It worked but It's taking time process when I have data in Billons.

```
final_data.write.parquet('s3://bucket/temp/')
df = spark.read.parquet('s3://bucket/temp/')
df.write.parquet('s3://bucket/old_data/')
```

I want to reduce this Temp writing & reading part.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you just union your old data with your new data, why not using `append` write mode to write new data directly in old data directory ? `new_data.write.parquet('s3://bucket/old_data/', 'append')`

Comment: We can't do that @VincentDoba I have updated Question with actual code. Check it once. We can't use save mode as "append"

Answer (score 0):

**You need to perform an action to trigger dataframe caching.** Thus you should modify the last lines of your code snippet as follow:

```py
...
final_data = final_data.cache()
final_data.count()
final_data.write.parquet('s3://bucket/old_data/')
```

By performing a `count` action on your dataframe, you trigger caching process and then be able to write on same directory from where your read.

However, I don't know if this will improve performance of your application as cache fallback to disk write when dataframe is too huge for memory. If your use case is updating parquet files, I advise you to look at [DeltaLake](https://docs.delta.io/latest/index.html) that was created to solve this.